# Sound balance keeps changing on High Sierra and Mojave

Tags: applescript, high-sierra, audio, mojave, sound-volume

i have a problem that every time when i reconnected my Bose QC35 II the sound balance was to the right instead of balanced in the middle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i found a solution on Reddit with the AppleScript but this did not work completely form me because it was throwing errors sometime:
`"System Events got an error: Can’t get tab group 1 of window 1 of process \"System Preferences\". Invalid index." number -1719 from tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"`

original source of the code: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/34qmn0/is_there_a_shortcut_or_command_to_switch_the_lr/

## Original code:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
     activate
     reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
     tell slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
          set value to 0.5
     end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences"
     quit
end tell
```

## Working code

I made some changes to the code:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"
        end repeat
        tell slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Sound"
            set value to 0.5
        end tell
        
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

i saved my code in `~/Applications/FixSoundBalance.applescript`

## Cronjob way

And made a crontab `crontab -e` with the value:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/osascript ~/Applications/FixSoundBalance.applescript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And on Mojave, you need to give the first time permissions to Cron to access Accessibility (under Security & Privacy, tab privacy), after that, it works fine.

## Alfred way

When you use the alfredapp https://www.alfredapp.com/, you can set the under `Features -> Default Results -> Extras` the checkbox `AppleScripts` then when you search for Fix... you get the script as result and you can run it directly. Then you do not need to set a cronjob.

Answer (score 2):

This free app also solves the problem:

https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/balance_lock/

> Headphones a little off? Noticing your audio isn't quite centred?
>   Enter Balance Lock - it will keep your audio centred and prevent
>   left/right drift.
>
> It's the perfect utility for making sure when plugging and unplugging
>   headphones that the audio stays centred. It was designed out of
>   frustration of the long standing OS X bug where the audio balance can
>   randomly move away from the center.
>
> It's simple to use and runs in the background un-intrusively.
>
> Download it now, completely for free to enjoy perfect audio that is no
>   longer slightly off balance!